# before_create method in model not working - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am unsure why my boolean is not automatically being set to false when a company is created. could one kindly advise me why.

- i am using the `before_create` method in the model

you help or advise would be much appreciated

#### schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: ############) do
  create_table "companies", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "companyname"
    t.string   "tel"
    t.string   "email"
    t.boolean  "fake"
  end
end
```

#### company.rb

Have I written the `set_company_as_false` method correctly?

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category_businesstype
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy

  before_create :set_company_as_false

  def set_company_as_false
    self.fake == false
    # if false it means company is not a fake/dummy company
  end
end
```

#### Terminal

```
Started POST "/companies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-09 12:08:11 +0100
Processing by CompaniesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"siKCe0npwA/sICpaCSds+vxWLw1ftv7z4s3tuNITJOM=", "company"=>{"companyname"=>"Event Ninja", "companyimage"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f83a463c2c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/72/z21dh3tx6jb03dscv7m3wc_h0000gn/T/RackMultipart20160609-772-nbq6po>, @original_filename="eventnj.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"company[companyimage]\"; filename=\"eventnj.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "email"=>"info@eventninja.io", "link"=>"https://twitter.com/eventninjaio", "tel"=>"+447961262477", "category_country_id"=>"3", "city"=>"London", "category_staff_id"=>"1", "category_companyage_id"=>"2", "category_businesstype_id"=>"1", "category_advert_id"=>"25"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered shared/_header_signedout.html.erb (1.8ms)
  CategoryCountry Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "category_countries".* FROM "category_countries"
  CategoryStaff Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "category_staffs".* FROM "category_staffs"
  CategoryCompanyage Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "category_companyages".* FROM "category_companyages"
  CategoryBusinesstype Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "category_businesstypes".* FROM "category_businesstypes"
  CategoryAdvert Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "category_adverts".* FROM "category_adverts"
  Rendered companies/_form.html.erb (956.0ms)
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "stories"
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (2.0ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "category_countries".* FROM "category_countries"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "category_staffs".* FROM "category_staffs"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "category_companyages".* FROM "category_companyages"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "category_businesstypes".* FROM "category_businesstypes"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "category_adverts".* FROM "category_adverts"
  Rendered companies/_form.html.erb (605.7ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "stories"
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_responsive_companies_form.html.erb (611.9ms)
  Rendered companies/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1579.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10049ms (Views: 10041.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

**controller**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  #load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    if user_signed_in?
      if current_user.admin_pa_management_group
        @user = current_user
        @company = @user.company
      else
        redirect_to errorpermission_path
      end
    else
      @company = Company.new
    end
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to(new_user_registration_path, notice: 'Company was successfully created.') }
        format.json  { render json: @company, status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json  { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    end

    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:companyname, :tel, :email, :category_staff_id, :category_country_id, :category_advert_id, :category_businesstype_id, :category_companyage_id, :city, :town, :latitude, :longitude, :address, :image, :link, :companyimage, :postcode, :about, :linklinkedin, :fake)
    end
end
```

Comment: Well, where's your controller?

Comment: "Have I written the set_company_as_false method correctly?" - as a matter of fact, no. Should be `self.fake = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your `set_company_as_false` method like this.

**company.rb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category_businesstype
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy

  before_create :set_company_as_false

  def set_company_as_false
    self.fake = false
    # if false it means company is not a fake/dummy company
  end
end
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: i'm not being redirected to the new_user_registration_path - the company is not being created even with the method written correctly - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use assign `=` operator on the callback method.

```
self.fake = false
```

Also, I'm wondering why don't you made that `fake` column as `default: false` in the migration file. It is more easy and simple than a callback.

Answer (score 0):

As your method says set_company_as_false, so it seems like you want to set your company as false. Hence the method would be:

```
def set_company_as_false
   self.fake = false
end
```

Let me know if you are trying to do something else